# Read a CSV File Delimited with Hash

Tags: csv, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a CSV export from an LDAP DB and I have to read data with a Classic ASP page.

The format of the CSV file is like

```
CRDLVR47E67L781V#1653#CORDIOLI#ELVIRA#658#elvira.cordioli@sender.at#SI
```

I can read the file line by line, and have to split the line manually. 
If I change the `#` value to a comma I can access the file by column. Can I make the asp page able to access the file by column, in order to obtain the single value keeping the `#` separator?

My connection string is

```
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 
oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=http://export/caselle.csv;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'"
```

and I can read line from the CSV file with the query

```
Set RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
RS.open "SELECT * FROM utenti_aospbo.csv", oConn
```

now I can only read `rs.fields(0)`, that output the entire line, like

```
CRDLVR47E67L781V#1653#CORDIOLI#ELVIRA#658#elvira.cordioli@sender.at#SI
```

I'd like to have

```
response.write rs.fields(0) 'CRDLVR47E67L781V
response.write rs.fields(5) 'elvira.cordioli@sender.at
```

Comment: Just specify the delimiter in the connection string `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=http://export/caselle.csv;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Format=Delimited(#)'"`. The `Format` property can specify the value using `Format=Delimited(<value>)`. See [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/delimited-columns/)

Comment: Useful article - [Much ADO About Text Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While I can't rule out that there is some version of OLEDB that does HTTP or accepts FMT **and** FORMAT in the connection string, I'm sure that the Data Source property of an ADODB Text connection needs to be a **folder**.

Instead of trying to specify a **global** separator in the connection string or the in the registry, I'd use a schema.ini file to describe the meta info in a file specific way.

All in one:

```
cscript 41224005.vbs
.\41224005.vbs
Option Explicit

Dim oFS  : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sF
For Each sF In Split(".\41224005.vbs ..\data\schema.ini ..\data\data1.txt")
    WScript.Echo sF
    WScript.Echo oFS.OpenTextFile(sF).ReadAll()
    WScript.Echo "---------------"
Next
Dim sDir : sDir    = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\")
Dim sCS  : sCS     = Join(Array( _
                          "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
                        , "Data Source=" & sDir _
                        , "Extended Properties='" & Join(Array( _
                               "text" _
                           ), ";") & "'" _
                     ), ";")
Dim oDb  : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oDb.Open sCS
'WScript.Echo oDb.ConnectionString
Dim oRS  : Set oRS = oDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM [data1.txt]")
WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).Value
WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(6).Value
oRS.Close
oDb.Close

---------------
..\data\schema.ini
[data1.txt]
FORMAT=Delimited(#)
ColNameHeader=False

---------------
..\data\data1.txt
CRDLVR47E67L781V#1653#CORDIOLI#ELVIRA#658#elvira.cordioli@sender.at#SI

---------------
CRDLVR47E67L781V
SI
```

Comment: y, but my problem is that i need this code working in an ASP.NET page, not in a vbs...