# VBscript check to see if an element of 1 array exist in another array if so output

Tags: arrays, vbscript

Hey guys I have 2 text files that look like

```
Text File 1              Text File2
    1,asd         |         4,sfsdfsdf,sdfdsf             
    2,dsf         |         5,werewr,errret
    3,dfg         |         6,rty,dfgree,werer
    4,dfg         |         7,sdf,werwer,asdd
    5,fgh         |         8,tye,werew,rtyrt
```

I want to check file2 to see if column1( the numbers ) match up with file1 . And then print content from file2 out to a file. In this case 4 and 5 match

```
Desired Result :      4,sfsdfsdf,sdfdsf             
                      5,werewr,errret
```

I have

```
 Dim arrFileLines() 
 Dim myarray()
 Dim line
 Dim eachline
 Dim found
 Dim tokenid

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(internal_txt, 1)

 Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
   arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
   line=arrFileLines(i)
   eachline=split(line,",")
   tokenid=eachline(0)   
  ' wscript.echo tokenid
   i = i + 1
 Loop
 objFile.Close

 Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(disabled_txt, 1)

 Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   Redim Preserve myarray(j)
   myarray(j) = objFile.ReadLine
   j = j + 1
 Loop
 objFile.Close



For l = lbound(arrFileLines) to ubound(arrFileLines) Step 1

    if arrFileLines(l) = myarray(l) then
        wscript.echo arrFileLines(l)
    end if 

  'wscript.echo arrFileLines(l)

 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be solved by doing an SQL Inner Join on your txt files. This is easy with [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms974559.aspx). Demo:

```
cscript 42843704-2.vbs
--------------- .\42843704-2.vbs
Option Explicit

Const adClipString =          2 ' 00000002

Dim oFS  : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sF
For Each sF In Split(".\42843704-2.vbs .\schema.ini .\42843704-1.txt .\42843704-2.txt")
    WScript.Echo "---------------", sF
    WScript.Echo oFS.OpenTextFile(sF).ReadAll()
    WScript.Echo
Next
Dim sDir : sDir    = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\")
Dim sCS  : sCS     = Join(Array( _
                          "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
                        , "Data Source=" & sDir _
                        , "Extended Properties='" & Join(Array( _
                               "text" _
                           ), ";") & "'" _
                     ), ";")
Dim oDb  : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oDb.Open sCS
'WScript.Echo oDb.ConnectionString
' From simple SELECT to INNER JOIN in 4 easy steps
'Dim sSQL : sSQL = "SELECT A.ID FROM [42843704-1.txt] AS A"
'Dim sSQL : sSQL = "SELECT A.ID, B.BB, B.CC FROM [42843704-1.txt] AS A, [42843704-2.txt] AS B"
'Dim sSQL : sSQL = "SELECT A.ID, B.BB, B.CC FROM [42843704-1.txt] AS A, [42843704-2.txt] AS B WHERE A.ID = B.I
D"
Dim sSQL : sSQL = "SELECT A.ID, B.BB, B.CC FROM [42843704-1.txt] AS A INNER JOIN [42843704-2.txt] AS B ON A.ID
 = B.ID"
WScript.Echo sSQL
Dim oRS  : Set oRS = oDb.Execute(sSQL)
WScript.Echo oRS.GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "nix")
oRS.Close
oDb.Close


--------------- .\schema.ini
[42843704-1.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(,)
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1=ID Integer
Col2=AA Char Width 50

[42843704-2.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(,)
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1=ID Integer
Col2=BB Char Width 50
Col3=CC Char Width 50


--------------- .\42843704-1.txt
1,asd
2,dsf
3,dfg
4,dfg
5,fgh


--------------- .\42843704-2.txt
4,sfsdfsdf,sdfdsf
5,werewr,errret
6,rty,dfgree,werer
7,sdf,werwer,asdd


SELECT A.ID, B.BB, B.CC FROM [42843704-1.txt] AS A INNER JOIN [42843704-2.txt] AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
4       sfsdfsdf        sdfdsf
5       werewr  errret
```

To see that this strategy really 'works' and scales well, compare the above to [SameMethodForOtherProblem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246422/603855)

P.S. Use a 32 Bit console on a 64 Bit windows machine to be able to access the driver.

P.P.S. To get a 64 Bit driver, follow the crumbs from [a](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) to [b](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255), install the 64 bit driver, and change **1** line of the demo:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
```

to

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions/changes about your approach.
First - if you don't need the text, and only the number, I would suggest using a List( of Number ) (check syntax, my VB is rusty) rather than an array.  The List.Add() will come in handy and essentially do the resizing for you.  Also - don't waste the memory to store what comes after the comma, since it is unnecessary.

Secondly - there is no reason to store the second file AT ALL.  That can be read through, and use List.Contains(value pulled from line read in second file) line by line to determine output.

Finally, The point above is key - for the way you have structured it, the check at the end is wrong.  You are only checking matching elements, and not scanning the original list.
Meaning:

```
if arrFileLines(l) = myarray(l) then
```

will only compare the first line to the first line,the second to the second, etc.